# Converting &amp; to & etc

Tags: c#, html-encode, string-conversion

I want to convert `&amp;` to &, `&quot;` to " etc.
Is there a function in c# that could do that without writing all the options manually?

Answer (score 118):

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()
```

**Edit**: Note from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx) that "To encode or decode values outside of a web application, use..."

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()
```

Comment: @AbuHamzah it should not work for &amp but it should work for &amp;

Comment: @BartoszWojcik This method has been around since .NET 1.1.  See MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332854%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I use 4.7.1 but cant find `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`

Comment: Rishav, we need to add reference to System.Web in order to use the function.

Answer (score 31):

Use the static method

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode
```

to change `&` to `&amp;` and `"` to `&quot;`. Use

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode
```

to do the reverse.

Answer (score 21):

You can use `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(uri);`

Comment: @AmirNo-Family If you are not in a web application, then yes, you need the System.Net.WebUtility version.  Otherwise, System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode works just fine.

Answer (score 8):

```
using System.Web; 
...
var html = "this is a sample &amp; string"; 
var decodedhtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html);
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should explain what the code does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 4):

[Server.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke.aspx).

Comment: This works in ASP.NET. But otherwise, Matt's answer is better.

Comment: I was assuming ASP.NET. The documentation mentions HttpUtility's HtmlDecode, as this is what Server.HtmlEncode calls anyway. Its easy to work this out by reading the documentation- Server.HtmlEncode's documentation actually explains what it does, unfortunately HttpUtility.HtmlDecode's doesn't.

Answer (score -7):

For .NET < 4 simple encoder

```
    public static string HtmlEncode(string value)
    {
        return value.Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("\"", "&quot;").Replace("'", "&apos;");
    }
```