# Encoding issue: can't find the item in db although it exists

Tags: c#, encoding, decoding

I have this entry in my db:

```
tést
```

What I get from the user is:

```
"t&eacute;st"
```

and when I'm searching it in db I get null results, because it doesn't exist.
How to convert `&eacute;` to é?

This is my code:

```
(from x in db.tblMyTable where x.name == "t&eacute;st" select x)
```

I use entity framework.

Comment: "When I'm seaching it in the db"... Which DB? How are your "searching". Where's your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting &amp; to & etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562360/converting-amp-to-etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert that string, you would use the HtmlDecode method:

```
str = Server.HtmlDecode(str);
```

However, you should look into why the value comes HTML encoded when it really shouldn't.